# -I and -isystem different behaviour when compiling

Tags: c++, cmake, avr

I have 3 CMake projects: myapp-avr (executable for AVR), myapp-unix (executable for Unix) and my_lib (a c++ static library imported by the executables). When I compile the MyLib project I have no problems at all. I can also successfully compile both myapp-avr and myapp-unix projects. However, I get errors when linking my app-avr such as "undefined reference to".

I uploaded an example to GitHub: https://github.com/cajomferro/basic-cmake. I have based my CMake structure on Pablo Ariasal sample project: https://github.com/pabloariasal/modern-cmake-sample.

I now know that the problem is related with the -isystem option. How can it be that the same exact command works with -I option but not with -isystem option (which is the one intended for imported/vendor libraries)?

**Doesn't work: (auto-generated by CMake)**

*/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avr-g++ -DARDUINO=10805 -DF_CPU=16000000L -**isystem** mylib/include -Os -g -w -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -std=gnu++11 -o src/main.cpp.obj -c src/main.cpp*

**Works:**

*/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avr-g++ -DARDUINO=10805 -DF_CPU=16000000L -**I** mylib/include -Os -g -w -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -std=gnu++11 -o src/main.cpp.obj -c src/main.cpp*

---

According to avr-g++ manual, -isystem means: *Search dir for header files, after all directories specified by -I but before the standard system directories. Mark it as a system directory, so that it gets the same special treatment as is applied to the standard system directories*

Moreover, when reading about the -I options, avr-g++ says: *you should not use this option to add directories that contain vendor-supplied system header files (use -isystem for that)*

I suppose this is the reason why CMake automatically generates a Make file with the *-isystem* option rather than using *-I*. Because in my CMake configuration I link libraries with the find_package() command, CMake interprets this as a vendor-supplied system?!

This project works just fine with clang (which also uses -isystem). My problem is with avr-g++.

Anyone had problems before with the *-isystem* using avr-g++? Is it possible to force CMake to use *-I*?? Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is here.  The `-I` and `-isystem` do different things.  So... the things they do are different.  Related.  But different.  Most 3rd party libraries ought to be done with `-I`, except for the few that feign to be the other kind (I'm looking at you, Boost).

Comment: Maybe you included the header once inside an `extern "C"` block and then you included it again outside of such a block.  Without a [mcve], it is hard to tell what you are doing wrong.  Make sure you do not include headers inside `extern "C"` blocks, and also put `#pragma once` at the top of your header to make sure it only gets included once.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I updated my question in order to better explain my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Apparently -isystem has a different behaviour on GNU compiler, according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html:

> On very old systems, some of the pre-defined system header directories
>   get even more special treatment. GNU C++ considers code in headers
>   found in those directories to be surrounded by an extern "C" block.

These guys had a similar problem: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/269.

So in order to avoid this mess, just inform CMake to use -I instead. A simple line is needed: NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED ON (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html).

A example is:

```
set_target_properties(my_target
    PROPERTIES
    NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED ON
    )
```

A full example is found in my CMakeLists.txt of myapp-avr executable: https://github.com/cajomferro/basic-cmake/blob/master/myapp-avr/CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Ah! And don't forget to search "-isystem" surrounded by those quotation marks otherwise Google will ignore it ;)

Comment: This is exact solution. Man this "feature" is sooo hidden it's borderline a bug.